# Thread example - notify() before wait()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have following Thread example:

```
class TickTock {
    String state; // contains the state of the clock

    synchronized void tick(boolean running) {
        if(!running) { // stop the clock 
            state = "ticked";
            notify(); // notify any waiting threads 
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("Tick ");
        state = "ticked"; // set the current state to ticked
        notify(); // let tock() run 
        try {
            while(!state.equals("tocked"))
                wait(); // wait for tock() to complete 
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted.");
        }
    }

    synchronized void tock(boolean running) {
        if(!running) { // stop the clock 
            state = "tocked";
            notify(); // notify any waiting threads 
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Tock");
        state = "tocked"; // set the current state to tocked
        notify(); // let tick() run 
        try {
            while(!state.equals("ticked"))
                wait(); // wait for tick to complete 
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted.");
        }
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thrd;
    TickTock ttOb;

    // Construct a new thread. 
    MyThread(String name, TickTock tt) {
        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
        ttOb = tt;
        thrd.start(); // start the thread 
    }

    // Begin execution of new thread. 
    public void run() {

        if(thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") == 0) {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++) ttOb.tick(true);
            ttOb.tick(false);
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++) ttOb.tock(true);
            ttOb.tock(false);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadCom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TickTock tt = new TickTock();
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Tick", tt);
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Tock", tt);

        try {
            mt1.thrd.join();
            mt2.thrd.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }
    }
}
```

How it comes that mt2 is waiting for mt1? Is that because mt1 is created before mt2 and therefore enters the synchronized method first? If yes - next question is: Why mt1 calls notify() before wait()? How can be the monitor released without calling wait()?

I understand it this way: mt1: I can not do any more work here so I will wait() and then I notify() mt2.

Now when I am writing this I realized that maybe thread that calls wait() can no longer call any other methods? So maybe that is why notify() needs to be called first?

Can someone please explain it to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How it comes that mt2 is waiting for mt1?

After `mt2` sets the state to "tocked", it waits until it gets changed to "ticked". Only `mt1` can do that.

> Is that because mt1 is created before mt2 and therefore enters the synchronized method first?

It doesn't matter which thread enters the method first. Each one waits for the other if necessary. If the thread that can make forward progress gets the lock first, it makes forward progress. If the wrong thread gets the lock, it just waits for the other, releasing the lock and allowing that thread to make forward progress.

> If yes - next question is: Why mt1 calls notify() before wait()?

Since `mt` has changed the `state` and another thread might be waiting for the state to change, it's important to call `notify`. Calling `wait` first would be a disaster -- the other thread might be waiting to get notified about the change this thread made and two threads waiting for each other is a deadlock.

> How can be the monitor released without calling wait()?

It can't be. But it doesn't matter. The thread will release the monitor either when it is entirely finished or when it's waiting for the other thread. In all other cases, it's actively modifying shared states and you don't want the lock released.

Comment: I started threads with simple programs. I created class with synchronized method. This method was executed by two or more 
threads and I understand that the method needed to be synchronized since two threads were using it at the same time. Now
I have one object with two different methods - so why they need to be synchronized? Can you pleease explain to me what happen
in 2 first prints?

Comment: I was confused because I thought that both threads enters tick() and tock() at the same time so first two 
prints ("Tick Tock") are only the question about order of the commands, because when you enter the method there is no control
neither in tick() ot tack() about what thread is executing. So both System.out.println(Tick/Tack) can be executed when threads
entered them. And why mt1 or mt2 need to wait on each other when every thread executes it's own method?

Comment: @vviston The purpose of the code is to demonstrate how to handle the case where a thread reaches a point where it cannot make forward progress until another thread reaches some point.

Comment: I realized that I had problem with understanding the concept that only one thread at the time is executing the synchronized method. I thought that both threads can use the same object methods, but according to Oracle, the object is locked completely when on thread is executing one of the object's method. I did not know that.